# ANDROID--How to take one part of html tag with fromHtml?

Tags: android, html, parsing, fromhtml

I want to take one part of description from html tag. But I do not know how can I apply it?

Here is my Html tag:

[image]

**İstanbul Çağlayan Adliyesi’nde teröristler tarafından silahla vurularak öldürülen savcı Mehmet Selim Kiraz’ın babası hastanede taziyeleri kabul ederken, yakınları da gözyaşı döktü. Savcı Kiraz’ın cenazesi Adli Tıp Kurumu morguna götürüldü.**

I need to parse this part from description.

**The following code give me all sentences in the description but I don't want some sentences which are in  `<a href=...></a>` tags:**

```
viewHolder.txtViewDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(itemsData.get(position).getDescription()));
```

How can I apply it? 
Thanks for help...

Comment: don't post html-code as image! Paste it as text ad format it as code.

Comment: I just want to say: I don't not. don;t waiting for my answer.thanks

Comment: But it is not html-code it is Json code.

Comment: You need to parse this or substring it, please be more specific what part you need so people can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Regular expression to remove all anchor tags.

```
String your_string = "<a>your html content</a>useful text"
String exp = "<a href=.*</a>";
String result = your_string.replaceAll(exp, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, you are trying to get the whole text, but without this from  tags, so you could use a regex like this

```
str = str.replaceAll("<a href=([^<]*)>([^<]*)</a>", "");
```

and remove all  tags. Then you could use the line you wrote to extract the text

```
viewHolder.txtViewDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(itemsData.get(position).getDescription()));
```

Hopefully this helps you

Comment: Yes that was my problem. Nevertheless it is not removing <a=href>...</a>

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression for replacing all the hyperlink tags.

```
String regx = "<a [\\s]*href .*></a>";
String result = description.replaceAll(regx);
```